# Decode the user name returned by facebook API

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook API to get data from facebook like this:

```
$me = $facebook->api('/me');
$name = utf8_decode($me['name']);
```

The Correct name has to be: **Gábriš**

Without utf8_decode, the result is: **GĂˇbriĹˇ**

And if I use utf8_decode, the result is incorrect again : **Gábri?**

Anyone has any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Yoo can your page header charset utf-8

Comment: Already tried it. It isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Correct name has to be: Gábriš
>
> Without utf8_decode, the result is: GĂˇbriĹˇ

Then you are not using UTF-8 for your page (or wherever you are using this value) – because Facebook *does* return all data in UTF-8.

> And if I use utf8_decode, the result is incorrect again : Gábri?

utf8_decode decodes to ISO-8859-1 – which does not contain some of the characters in the original name, so this is total nonsense.

> Anyone has any clue?

What are you *actually* trying to achieve? What encoding are you using for your page? If it’s not UTF-8 (which in general for pages on the web it should be), try the iconv functions to transcode it to whatever encoding you are using (provided this one can represent those characters).

Answer (score 0):

Insert the code in your DB Connection:

```
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8");
```